# ¿Cómo cambiar el icono de navegación que viene por defecto en Google Maps en Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api, geolocalización

vengo a realizar una consulta, actualmente me encuentro realizando una aplicación tipo GPS esta utiliza diferentes paquetes entre ellos estoy utilizando Google Maps Flutter para mostrar el mapa y demás.
[image: Quiero cambiar este icono azul]

Lo que busco es cambiar este icono azul que viene por defecto para mostrar la ubicación del usuario por uno personalizado como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que esto se debe hacer utilizando BitmapDescriptor, pero mi problema esta en que estoy utilizando Bloc para el manejo de estado y no se como actualizar este icono nuevo con el movimiento del usuario.

Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrias hacer es setear a false myLocationEnabled del widget GoogleMap para que desaparezca el icono por defecto, si estas usando BLoC puedes envolver a GoogleMap con un BlocBuilder que va a construir el mapa cada que hagas algún cambio de estado, en este caso se haria un cambio de estado cada que actualices el marker personalizado con la nueva posición:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return BlocBuilder<MapBloc, MapState>(
   builder: (context, state) {
     return GoogleMap(
       initialCameraPosition: cameraPosition,
       myLocationEnabled: false,
       compassEnabled: false,
       myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
       zoomControlsEnabled: false,
       markers: state.markers.values.toSet(),
       mapToolbarEnabled: false,
     );
   },
 );
}
```

te recomiendo el paquete [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) el cual es muy práctico por que posee un stream que recibe las actualizaciones de ubicación a través de un objeto Position, este objeto tiene un atributo llamado heading que calcula el rumbo en el que viaja el dispositivo y es muy util para que tu marcador personalizado pueda rotar.

La ubicación con geolocator la puedes obtener de la siguiente forma:

```
 Geolocator.getPositionStream(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high) 
  .listen((Position position) {
  if (position != null) {
    final currentlatLng = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    //TODO: Crear marcador y emitir nuevo estado con el marcador nuevo
    Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId('user'),
    position: currentlatLng ,
    rotation: position.heading,
    draggable: false,
    zIndex: 2,
    flat: true,
    anchor: Offset(0.5, 0.5),
    icon: markerAsset //Tu marker creado usando BitmapDescriptor
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Gracias Diego, me ha servido tu respuesta, yo estaba usando Geolocator con el getPositionStream pero mi problema radicaba en que no aparecia el icono esto se debia a que como estoy utilizando un emulador para probar no detectaba movimiento por lo que el icono no se renderizaba, ya lo he solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

No es posible por ahora, hay un issue abierto en el repo de `Flutter` con la etiqueta del plugin que usas.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31571

Mi sugerencia es que deshabilites tu ubicación del mapa, captures tu ubicación actual y con eso puedes añadir un Marker que será tu posición, ahí podrás usar la imagen que desees.

Si no sabes como hacerlo te recomiendo este codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-in-flutter#4

Comment: Gracias Diego, si veo que es un problema que muchos usuarios ya han reportado y que estaría bueno que se hiciera el update al paquete para realizarlo de una manera mas sencilla, ya he podido resolver el problema utilizando sus respuestas como guía.